# Modeling Nullable Composite Foreign Key in Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have a data type with a composite foreign key. One of the columns can be null, in which case it means that there is no foreign entity to be mapped to (this is modeling a tree, so that element is the root of the tree). How can I store this in Hibernate?

```
@Nullable
@ManyToOne(optional=true)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="tree_id", referencedColumnName="tree_id"),
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="node_id", nullable=true),
})
public TreeNode getParent() {
    return parent;
}
```

This fails whenever it trys to access the root node, saying it cannot find an entry with that key (I assume the key is `(tree_id, null)`, for which there is no corresponding entry).

I'm accessing nodes with an HQL query like so:

```
@Query("from TreeNode as tn where tn.treeId = ?2 and tn.parent.treeId = ?1")
```

Comment: Can you show the way you are trying to access?

Comment: I added it to the body of the post.

Comment: What is the relevance of this question? Is it a hibernate-specific issue or, JPA-specific (which is not the same) or MySQL (native SQL queries)? What I mean, please don't over-tag your posts. :-)

Beside that, where is `@Query` coming from? Is it masking a native (SQL) query or a JPQL query?

Comment: Hmm I wasn't sure if the issue was something with how mysql handles these composite foreign keys, or if it was a jpa or hibernate issue. That's why I used all three tags. As far as the query tag, it's written in HQL, so it is being executed by hibernate (which I assume is essentially equivalent to a JPQL query, although I'm not 100% sure).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most probably due to the fact that you are trying to compare **null** with **=** operator. In database you can never compare **null** with the help of **=** operator. In native queries too **null** is compared with **is** rather than **=**.

Thus, in this case  equivalent native sql query will be something like:

```
select [column list] from TreeNode as tn where tn.treeId = [treeId] and tn.parent.treeId = null;
```

Since two nulls can never be equal that is why your query returns you nothing.

In this case, you can use query as per the value of parent.treeId.

Let's say if the value of parent.treeId is **null**, then just trigger the below query:

```
@Query("from TreeNode as tn where tn.treeId = ?1")
```

and if the value of parent.treeId is **not null**, then trigger the query you are already writing.